Can we use both index with path properties in React Router v6?
I have to following routes for the settings page (inside the <Route path="settings/*">):
<Routes>
    <Route index path="account" element={<AccountDetails />} />
    <Route path="password" element={<ChangePassword />} />
    <Route path="notifications" element={<Notifications />} />
    <Route
        path="platform-settings"
        element={!canManageAllEnvironments ? <Navigate to=".. " /> : <Outlet />}
    >
        <Route index element={<PlatformGeneralSettings />} />
        <Route path="roles-and-permissions" element={<RolesAndPermissions />} />
        <Route path="banners" element={<Banners />} />
        <Route path="notifications" element={<EmailNotifications />} />
        <Route path="certificates" element={<Certificates />} />
    </Route>
    <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="." />} />
</Routes>

The account subpage is the index page, so if the user goes to the /settings/ route or the /settings/account route, they should see the account details subpage. Currently, if the route is settings/, nothing is being rendered although I am adding the index property in the account route. How should I deal with this case?
Expected to see the account subpage on /settings/ and /settings/account/ routes!

Although the Route component takes both an index and path prop it can't use both at the same time. The path prop will override the index prop, so this is why for <Route index path="account" element={<AccountDetails />} /> and URL path "/settings" that no route is matched and AccountDetails is not rendered, i.e. a blank page.
You will need to separate these into separate routes, the options you have are:

Render AccountDetails on both an index and regular route:
<Routes>
  <Route index element={<AccountDetails />} />
  <Route path="account" element={<AccountDetails />} />

  ....
</Routes>


Render AccountDetails on "*/account" and render a redirect from the index route to the account page:
<Routes>
  <Route index element={<Navigate to="account" replace />} />
  <Route path="account" element={<AccountDetails />} />

  ....
</Routes>


Render AccountDetails as the index route and render a redirect from the  account page to the index route:
<Routes>
  <Route index element={<AccountDetails />} />
  <Route path="account" element={<Navigate to="." replace />} />

  ....
</Routes>



